# Object Oriented APEX Anyone?

Tags: design-patterns, solid-principles

I am trying to make my APEX object-oriented.

Here's the ERD,

[image: Users, charges and Rates]

And here's the requirement

- A user can charge an opportunity based on the hours they spent and their grades.
- Grades are stored as a custom object under the user with **Valid From** and **Valid To** dates. If a user gets promoted, the **Valid To** on the previous grade record is updated and a new grade record is created
- As a user I can work on an opportunity and move on to the next; when the opportunity gets accepted, I get paid for the hours I worked on the record. But my manager gets paid when the recor d is closed.
- Calculation is based on the grade when I was working on the opportunity and not based on my current grade.
- Daily rates get updated every year.

**Object Oriented Approach**

```java
Class RateCalculation(){
            
    Opportunity opp;
    Charge managerCharge;
    Charge developerCharge;
    Charge testerCharge;
        
    public static void calucalteRate(Opportunity opp){
        Id manager = opp.Manager__c;
        Id developer = opp.Developer__c;
        Id tester = opp.Tester__c;
            
        Date acceptedDate = opp.AcceptedDate__c;
        Date closeDate = opp.CloseDate__c;
        
        managerCharge = new Charge(manager, closeDate);
        developerCharge = new Charge(developer, acceptedDate);
        testerCharge = new Charge(tester, acceptedDate);
            
        updateCharges();
    }

    private updateCharges(){
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Id = opp.Id;
        opp.Managers_Rate = managerCharge.getHourlyRate();
        opp.Decvelopers__Rate = developerCharge.getHourlyRate();
        opp.Tester__Fee = testerCharge.getHourlyRate();
        Update opp;
    }
}
```

**Charge Class**

```java
public with sharing class Charge {
    User user;
    String userGrade;
    Date calculationDate;
    static List<Rates__c> rates;
    Static List<Grade__c> Grades;
    String userName;
    Decimal hourlyRate;
    
    public ESOCPP_Charge(Id userId, Date calculationDate) {
        this.calculationDate = calculationDate;
        getUser(userId);
        getUserGrades(userId);
    }

    public getHourlyRate(){
        Rate__c rate = getRates();
        if(userGrade == '1'){
            return rate.Level_1_Day_Rate__c;
        }
        if(userGrade == '2'){
            return rate.Level_2_Day_Rate__c;
        }
        if(userGrade == '3'){
            return rate.Level_3_Day_Rate__c;
        }
        if(userGrade == '4'){
            return rate.Level_4_Day_Rate__c;
        }
        throw new ChargeException('No rates were found for '+userName +'.');
    }
    
    private void getUser(Id userId){
        user = [SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE Id = :userId];
        
    }

    private void getUserLevel(Id userId){
        Grades =  [
            SELECT Level__c, User__r.FirstName, User__r.LastName
            FROM Grade__c 
            WHERE User__c = :userId 
            AND ValidFrom <= :calculationDate 
            AND ValidTo >= :calculationDate
        ];
        if(Grades.isEmpty()){
            throw new ChargeException('No grades found for '+userName +'.');
        } else if(Grades.size()>1){
            throw new ChargeException('Multiple grades found for '+userName +'.');
        } else {
            level = Grades[0].Level__c;
        }
    }
    
    private Rates__c getRates(){
        // check for a valid rate in the existing rates
        for(Rates__c rate: rates){
            if(isValid(rate)){
                return rate;
            }
        } 
        // if rate was not queried before, get it
        List<Rates__c> rateList = [
            SELECT Level_1_Day_Rate__c,
            Level_2_Day_Rate__c,
            Level_3_Day_Rate__c,
            Level_4_Day_Rate__c,
            ValidFrom,
            ValidTo
            FROM Rates__c
            WHERE ValidFrom <= :calculationDate
            AND ValidTo >= :calculationDate
            ORDER By CreatedDate DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ];
        if(rateList.isEmpty()){
            throw new ChargeException('No valid rates found for '+ userName +' for ' + calculationDate+ '.' );
        } else {
            return rateList[0];
        }
    }

    private Boolean isValid(Rates__c rate){
        // this rate is valid if the reconlication date falls in between the ValidFrom and ValidTo dates.
        return rate.ValidFrom <= calculationDate && calculationDate <= rate.ValidTo;
    }

    public class ChargeException extends Exception {}
}
```

**However**

I can write the same code with static methods and bulkify it for many users, like so.

```java
public without sharing class AppFeeReconciliation {
    Opportunity opp;
    static Map<Id, List<Grade__c>> userLevelsMap = new Map<Id, List<Grade__c>>;
    static List<Rates__c> Charges = List<Rates__c>();
    Date acceptedDate;
    Date closeDate;
    
    public static void calculateRates(Opportunity opp){
        AcceptedDate__c = opp.AcceptedDate__c;
        closeDate = opp.closeDate;
    
        getUserGrades();
        getRates();
        reconciliate();
        updateCharges();
    }

    private Set<Id> getUserIds(){
        Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>;
        userIds.add(opp.Manager__c);
        userIds.add(opp.Developer__c);
        userIds.add(opp.Tester__c);
        return userIds;
    }

    private void getUserGrades(){
        if(!getUserIds().isEmpty()){
            for(Grade__c grade : [
                SELECT Level__c, Valid_From__c, Valid_To__c
                FROM Grade__c 
                WHERE User__c = :userIds 
                AND Valid_From__c <= :acceptedDate AND Valid_To__c >= :acceptedDate
            ])
            {
                userGradessMap.put(grade.User__c, List<Grade__c>); // yes, I know this is not enough :)
            }
        }
    }

    private void getRates(){
            Charges rate : [
                SELECT Level_1_Day_Rate__c,
                Level_2_Day_Rate__c,
                Level_3_Day_Rate__c,
                Level_4_Day_Rate__c,
                Valid_From__c,
                Valid_To__c
                FROM Rates__c
                WHERE Valid_From__c <= :acceptedDate
                AND Valid_To__c >= :acceptedDate // Add other conditions if there are more dates to consider
            ];
        }
    }
    
    private decimal getHourlyRate(){
        // get user List<level__c> from userGradessMap, loop throuh it to get the level at a particular date
        // loop through the rates and get the rate based on the user level for that time
        // return the rate
    }
     
    private void updateCharges(){
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Id = opp.Id;
        opp.Managers_Rate = getHourlyRate(Opp.Manager__c);
        opp.Decvelopers__Rate = getHourlyRate(Opp.Developer__c);
        opp.Tester__Fee = getHourlyRate(Opp.Tester__c);
        Update opp;
    }
}
```

Second approach is not stricly object oriented, SOLID principles are also not considered here. But, I dont need to care about running into heap sizes, and is builkified too so it is safe for extension in case a new userlookup is added in the future. However the above object-oriented approach will fail with SOQL limits alone if more user lookups are added.

How can I make this striclty object oriened, and safe for APEX?

I have tried ffLib already. But I dont want to use it for this scenairio.

Comment: uhh, Apex is an OOP language (as opposed to other paradigms like imperative, functional, procedural, etc...), so your code is already "Object Oriented". Trying for "purity" and for strict adherence to design patterns/philosophies is often not a realistic or useful approach. The primary thing that code needs to do is to work (with being testable as a close second). You should rather focus on: 1) Working on collections rather than single records. 2) Minimize queries and DML. 3) Keep queries and DML outside of loops (direct or indirect) at all costs.

Comment: As such, the second approach would seem to have better bones, more in line with the realities we face in Salesforce. That said though, I wouldn't make `calculateRates()` static and `getHourlyRate()` would probably be better stored in a map (rather than using a chain of if-else if).

Comment: Use of static methods is, for me, an anti-pattern because it prevents the use of mocking in unit tests. I agree with @DerekF on all his points and add that use of instance methods and some form of dependency injection allows better unit test isolation via mocking (using the `StubProvider` or other approaches). All Salesforce code must be written with bulkification in mind, at least from the query and DML perspectives and, frequently, from the CPU and heap efficiency perspectives.

Comment: @DerekF Thank you for your useful comments. Yes, I was looking for 'purity' here and I realize now that it could not be the best way to deal with APEX governor limits. However, as part of learning, I was trying to bring in and apply some SOLID principles.

Comment: @PhilW the above method would be invoked from a trigger when the user records are populated. Could you please leave some pseudocode to explain how I can bring in some dependency injection in here?

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/sirephil/sf-async-from-trigger/blob/main/force-app/main/default/triggers/TriggeredEvent.trigger). The referenced [getInstance method](https://github.com/sirephil/sf-async-from-trigger/blob/main/force-app/main/default/classes/TriggeredEventHandler.cls) uses a factory that allows for dependency injection, mainly aimed at use in unit testing. This code base doesn't include any unit tests, so you can't see how a mock can be injected directly, but hopefully you'll get the idea.